# Which Communication Protocol to use for Communication between a Django App and an Android Client

Tags: django, rest

I am developing an Emergency Response System. I have developed my server using the Django Framework in Python. I have an Android Client which needs to communicate with the Server. My question is :

1) Should I use REST API for communicating between the Android App and the Django Server?

2) Or is there any other RPC methods (like RMI in Java) which should be used for communication?

3) The Client developed as an Android App needs to send requests/messages to the server based on the user interaction. Would a REST API be a good option?

Thanks.

Comment: What are your considerations so far? What exactly are your requirements?

Comment: I need to use a Communication Technology to communicate between the Android Client and the Server. So, I am just deciding up on the Client/Server Communication tech to use. REST is one option. I was wondering whether there would be any better choices

Answer (score 2):

Use HTTP. This is the easiest protocol available to you.

REST is an architecture pattern (it describes how you would design your API service and client). It is designed to use HTTP (a protocol).

In order to implement RMI you would have to find an implementation for JRMP on Android and then make sure that all your users have access to this over the network; you would also have to use TCP/IP which would be near impossible to implement separately on your remote clients (unless you have deep level control over them) and even then, the network should allow such access which most mobile providers will not.

It is not practical, and it will not work reliably.